# Abp DbMigrator-Why is it using wsl2?

Tags: c#, abp

wondering why is the dbMigrator using a wsl2 as a launch profile,
I'm having some issues running it: "localdb is not supported on this platform"
Any way to do it without wsl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a problem with your IDE. There is no obligation to use wsl in ABP. You can run it with the `dotnet run` command from CMD.